# Upload file on image click

Tags: jquery, ocupload

I have a page with multiple images on it. What I have done, is make it so a user clicks on the thumbnail and the file browser box comes up to upload a new image. This works by using the ocupload.js jquery extention.

This has been working well, except in IE10 the image click does not work the same way as it does in Firefox.

In firefox, I can click on the image and the browse for file box will show, On ie10, it requires a double click.

What I am trying to do is make it so ie10 will allow it to work with a single click instead of requiring a double click,

I think the issue has to do with the way IE handles clicking on a file upload box in general, On filefox you can click in the file upload box and the dialog will show, on IE it seems that clicking on the file upload box requires a double click.

So I am wondering how I would alter ocupload.js to give the same functionality to IE as firefox

Comment: can you post some codes pls or a jsfiddle?

Comment: Known issue, simple google shows several thousand results, why not just `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem,

I changed the ocupload.js file

There is probably better ways to fix it , but I fixed by changing:

```
    container.mousemove(function(e){
        input.css({
            top: e.pageY-container.offset().top+'px',
            left: e.pageX-container.offset().left+'px'
        });
    });
```

To:

```
    container.mousemove(function(e){

        var leftside = e.pageX-container.offset().left;

         if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'){
              leftside = e.pageX-container.offset().left - 50;

         }



        input.css({
            top: e.pageY-container.offset().top+'px',
            left: leftside+'px'
        });
    });
```